# select2-choices ui element: How to only allow entries that match tags?

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using the "select2-choices" element on a simple webapp.  I am able to populate the search entries with tag generated data, and both sorting and selecting work as expected.

However, users are still able to enter their own choices, even if they're not specified in the tags attribute:

```
tags:[{id: 1, text: 'red'}, {id: 2, text: 'green'}, {id: 3, text: 'blue'}]
```

If the user types "chartreuse" and hits enter, it gets added to the hidden field, and thus to the form input.

[image]

How do I prevent this, and allow only items that match the tags?